# Can you generate more heat than the amount of work done?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, energy-conservation, work, dissipation

I have doubt regarding how can COP of a refrigerator can be one!
It can happen only when heat is more extracted when work inputed or rate of heat absorbed is more than power? Can any one of the reason is correct?
Explain!

Comment: A refrigerator is not neutralizing or cooling heat, it is just moving heat. You can move 100 kJ of heat with only 50 kJ energy input for instance.

Comment: A refrigerator moves entropy from a lower temperature to a higher temperature at the cost of mechanical work input. On the contrary, a heat engine obtains mechanical work by allowing entropy to drop from a higher temperature to a lower temperature.

Answer (score 1):

A refrigerator (that is, a *heat pump*) can have a COP greater than one because it is scooping up existing heat that is essentially lying around the place and then moving it somewhere else, rather than having to make the heat from scratch.